# Java Circular Reference - Can’t Compile

Tags: java, circular-dependency

**File: A.java**

```
class A
{
    B b;
    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }
}
```

**File: B.java**

```
class B
{
    public B() {}
    public foo(A a) {...}
}
```

The above code can not be compiled because A needs B before it can compile and B needs A before it can compile.  Neither shall compile before the other.  Now what?

This example is trivial.  I could remove foo(A a) {...} such B.java would compile.  Then compile A.java.  Restore B.java then compile it.  But I’m trying to build RXTX from source and its dependencies are a maze of twisty little phrases.

I had hoped that I could compile to non-working class code.  Then with all the classes and methods defined compile again into working code.

Is there a magic bullet?

Comment: This should compile fine in Java.

Comment: This *does* compile fine in Java, except for the compilation error with `public foo(A a) {...}` (missing return type).

Comment: Circular dep. are not nice, but they compile.

Comment: your foo should be void foo(...) , but this you already know I guess.

Comment: the magic bullet is spelled c l a s s p a t h :)

Comment: I guess the question is kind of "how Java is intelligent enough to resolve the circular dependency?"

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Answer (score 7):

They should compile fine if you compile them both at once:

```
javac A.java B.java
```

Comment: javac -classpath . A.java should compile fine too, as long as B.java is in the same package. Or as long as it can be find in the classpath.

Comment: It does compile fine, but *not* because of the `-classpath` directive: first of all, it works without it (as the current dir is by default included in both the classpath and sourcepath since Java 5) and secondly, **the option to use here is `-sourcepath`**, not `-classpath` (as that's where `javac` will look for *source* files) -- see the manual.

Answer (score 3):

There is no compilation problem, if you use a Java IDE (Eclipse, or Netbeans etc) or ant build script etc (the major thing is that it should be right classpath when using `javac` command).

or if you compile from the command line with `*.java`, `javac` is smarter than this ;)

```
javac -classpath ... *.java
```

The Java Compiler works from your classpath, this is rule no 1 in Java!

If you hava A and B source code, and you do a compilation with the right classpath then there is no problem with the javac task.

If you just do a compilation of your first class (A or B), the Java compiler will search the classpath for the requested classes (as specified in your import, if no import package is given, then the classpath should be as the selected class).

> If A.java and B.java are in the same package, and you do run a *javac -classpath . A.java* this should result in a A.class and B.class on the fly.
>
> If A.java is in package x and B in package y, you should of course use both classpaths during compilation. *javac -classpath x;y;.; A.java* (this will compile even B.java if it is not already compiled!)

Comment: -classpath has nothing to do with *.java files (as the very name infers). The option you're looking for is -sourcepath (which does fall back to the `classpath` if not explictly set).

Answer (score 0):

Or, break the circular dependency by using an interface -- if that's applicable in your case, of course.

c.java:

```
public interface C {...};
```

B.java:

```
public class B implements C {...};
```

A.java:

```
class A
{
    C b;
    public A() {
        b = // use a factory here, returning a C reference
    }
}
```

Thus, in compile time, both A and B depend on C -- but not on each other